# Hibernate Double precision auto-generation

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, floating-point, precision

I'm trying to create a database table automatically using Hibernate and I have a few columns that are of type double (in Java). These columns have different precisions associated with them. For example, you might want to see the speed of a vehicle like "56.23" km/h. However, right now I'm getting something like "56.232343536918" km/h.

I'm using the `<property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto">update</property>` property in my `hibernate.cfg.xml` file in order to automatically create the table using the associated mapping file.

Here's how I declared one the columns:

```
<property name="accelerometer_y" type="java.lang.Double">
    <column name="ACCELEROMETER_Y" precision="4" scale="2"/>
</property>
```

So from what I read about this in Hibernate, this is the proper way of declaring a MySQL data type of DOUBLE(4,2). However, when Hibernate automatically generates the table, I get DOUBLE, not DOUBLE(4,2). I don't get the precision and scale numbers that I've specified.

Does anybody see what's wrong in here?

Comment: have you tried with `@Column(precision=4, scale=2)` in your model class.

Comment: I marked this as a duplicate because when you say `DOUBLE` in MySQL you always get 64-bit IEEE floating point. And, when you use floating point, you need to handle the rounding yourself. It's just the nature of the floating point beast.

Comment: So you mean I should manually alter the tables? Isn't Hibernate supposed to create them automatically with the precision and scales that I have specified in the mapping file?